# Android: best practice for building a 2D avatar customization

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view, avatar

I am trying to create a **2D avatar customizer without using a Game Engine** inside my Android app.

I will basically have a PNG image as a base to start with. Then I want to layer other images on top of the base to customize the character.

What would be the best option to create this? I have already created a custom `ImageView` and overrided the `onDraw()`:

```
public class AvatarView extends ImageView {

public AvatarView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AvatarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AvatarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.battle_run_char), 0, 70, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red_cartoon_hat), 70, 0, null);
}

}
```

This seems very specific by using coordinates. Would there be a better way to achieve this without having to use coordinates?

EDIT:

Here is what I have so far. The guy is a separate image from the red hat.

[image]

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Edited original post. This is what I have so far. Just trying to see if this is the best way to do it before I put more effort and time into it. Was also looking at this app: http://androidify.com/ but unsure of how extensive the code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to add on that `ImageView` dynamically then there is not way to place those images without assigning pixel axis on it

one problem in your custom class is that dont ever `decodeResource` within your `onDraw` method that it will be called multiple times and it will cause a `big lag problem`, instead create an init method within your `AvatarView` and decode it, and call that init method in all of your constructor.

**sample:**

```
public class AvatarView extends ImageView {

private Bitmap body;
private Bitmap hat;
public AvatarView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public AvatarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public AvatarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init()
{
  body = getResources(), R.drawable.battle_run_char);
  hat = getResources(), R.drawable.red_cartoon_hat);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(body , 0, 70, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(hat , 70, 0, null);
}

}
```

Comment: Duly noted about decoding resources. Would you recommend (in your opinion) that this would be a good option for avatar customization? That is doing custom views with coordinates. Adding a game engine just for the purpose of creating an avatar seems like overkill right??

Comment: @TheNomad I wont, remember all screens devices have different pixels count so when you try this on higher pixel count device it wont look like the picture above.

Comment: @TheNomad I would recommend using 1 image for each of the customization. but that would require a lot of images.

Comment: Hmm having 1 image for each customization seems like a hack job. Eventually we will have so many different combinations: hats, shirts, pants, gloves, etc there will be too many combinations. I'll have to look into other options. And thanks for the info on the other density sizes. Will look into SVG options.